# How can i edit file field in Django?

Tags: django

how can I change the input file in Django?I have 3 input fields. But I want to change 2 of them another one has to store old file from database. How can I restore it

Comment: Can you provide some code examples?

Comment: based on what you are using, if this is a django forms then override `save` method, if you are using DRF then override `update` method in the serializer

Comment: {% if work.list_agreement_file %}
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8"><input class="form-control"  id="list" name="list" value="{{ work.lislist_agreement_file }}" type="file" ></div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
        <a href="/{{ work.list_agreement_file }}" class="text-success">
      <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Ko'rish</button>
  </a>
  </div>
   </div>
{% else %}
  <input class="form-control" name="list" id="list" type="file">
{% endif %}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.